# How do you prohibit a CSS menu from overriding a standard HTML link?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, overriding, parent

I created a menu with CSS and have an HTML link below it using the a href tag. However, the link isn't blue or underlined, rather it looks and hovers exactly like a link that I made for the menu using CSS. Moreover, this link is shifted to the left regardless if I type the  tag after the text in which I want it to appear.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
ul
{
float:left;position:relative;width:40%;padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;
}
a
{
float:left;width:5em;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:black;background-color:#c0c0c0;padding:0.2em 0.5em;
}
a:hover {background-color:#d0d0d0;}
li {display:inline}
</style>

</head>

<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<br>
<br>

To see a picture of Curious George, click <a href="http://cdn.mhpbooks.com/uploads/2012/05/Curious_Georg.jpg">this link</a>

</html>
```

Here's what it looks like displayed:

http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/3938/vi22.jpg

Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I just started learning HTML/CSS this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your styles to take advantage of specificity:

```
<style>
ul {
    float:left;position:relative;width:40%;padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;
}
ul li a {
    float:left;width:5em;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:black;background-color:#c0c0c0;padding:0.2em 0.5em;
}
ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0d0d0; }
li { display:inline }
</style>
```

Here is a link to some more information on this: [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Sure thing! CSS is a pretty neat tool, but it can be confusing at times. :)

Comment: Hehe, yes. The first day I looked into it, I was overwhelmed and even had nightmares, haha. But I love how helpful everyone is. ;-)

Comment: @Sweersz While this solves your issue i suggest you take into consideration GuiGreg's answer as it teaches better organization of your css.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific with your css rules. As it is right now it apply to all  add and id for your menu or something like

```
#menu a {
  some css here
}
```

Comment: ul , was enough to fit to the question ;)

Comment: yes but it will cause another problem if he need another ul later

Comment: still, it won't style links anywhere else :)

Comment: I like this answer better seeing as it teaches the use of an id/class to organize the css rather than a random nesting of elements, which as stated can lead to other places unintentionally getting a style you don't desire.